# Drupal 7 - create own login form

Tags: forms, theming, users, 7

Is it possible to create own login form? I need to insert it into my basic page. It is campaign for my client and he wants to be able login from specific basic page. I have tried to use block from classic login, but without success. But it still has many things around (like remember me etc..), and I need only basic username/password

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just retrieve the form and print it on your node template. In your theme's template.php (a custom module would work too):

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full' && $variables['nid'] == 9 && user_is_anonymous()) {
        $variables['login_form'] = drupal_get_form('user_login');
    }
}
```

And then in either your theme's node.tpl.php or a specific node template if you're using one:

```
<?php if (isset($login_form)): ?>
  <?php print render($login_form); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will just print the same form you'd find at /user/login wherever you want it. Just make sure to replace the 9 with your node's nid.

Comment: Thank you, this is prefect first step. But it render login form with many fields around (header, perex, remember me... etc.). I need only username and password. Is it possible to achieve this without css hidding? Next think is redirection if I fill in wrong password, it redirects me to login page.
edit: it is inserting what is in user-login.tpl.php

Comment: Maybe by creating if statement inside user-login.tpl.php, but then I need to pass there some variable from call " drupal_get_form('user_login');" to recognize that this login form is for my specific page. I can not use node id here because I have there another login form in popup. Is it possible to pass some argument?

Comment: Try adding a couple lines to the hook_preprocess_node, one to change the theme - note the goal here is to not use your user-login.tpl.php, and just render the basic form without a template - and one line to add a destination to your form: `$variables['login_form']['#action'] .= '?destination=' . current_path();`
        `$variables['login_form']['#theme'] = '_custom';`

Comment: I have solved it a little bit different way. In **hook_preprocess_node** I just added: `$variables['login_form'] = drupal_get_form('user_login', "my_identificator");`... Then in **hook_form_alter** I added `if(reset($form_state['build_info']['args']) == "my_identificator"){`. So when is this if fullfiled, then I set `$form['login_type'] = array('#markup' => "my_identificator");`. Then in **user-login.tpl.php** I have if block `if(isset($form["login_type"]) && isset($form["login_type"]["#markup"]) && $form["login_type"]["#markup"] == "my_identificator") { ?>` where I render all what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you're looking for a way to do it without writing code, consider the [Login Toboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module.